# After upgrading from blender 3.0 to 3.2.1 Blender wont render animation properly in eevee

Tags: rendering, animation, eevee-render-engine

After upgrading from blender 3.0 to 3.2.1 Blender wont render animation properly in eevee.

Previously it was pretty simple and straight forward to render animations for me in Blender 3.0.0 in the EEVEE engine. Now that I just installed Blender 3.2.1 I cant render a simple animation and it just cuts to the checkerboard screen with nothing ever happening. Is there something I'm missing in this new version of blender? Everything seems to be running well in the 3D viewport with no lag or anything.

[me trying to render my animation](https://vimeo.com/734244288/4767f8208e)

Comment: i think lossless will not work with the H.264 encoding, or at least it has always been problematic for me. try another output quality aside from lossless

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie He has chosen only "Perceptually Lossless", which isn't actually lossless. I don't know if Blender can create lossless H.264, but in general it's possible: [h.264 lossless coding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701805/h264-lossless-coding) However, this might not be the issue, since it seems it's not the resulting video file that's not working but the rendering itself. But my problem is I can't reproduce the error with my Blender 3.2.1 - so there might be something with the hardware or some quite specific settings I cannot identify in the video.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann thanks for your input :) i always had problems with lossless and perceptually lossless with h.264, the render output was always corrupted for me. i remember i had a thread raising this issue and they told me it was not compatible. i can't find the thread..

Comment: Actually those are the settings I use every time I render with no issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually just figured it out, there's a problem with the object I made because I used add on geometry nodes, didn't think they would be an issue but I guess so. When I tried to render a different project it was totally fine. Guess I should have done more troubleshooting before asking but I appreciate the help. Thankyou

Comment: awesome! glad you discovered the issue :)